# Compacting giant Power Saving notification

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, notifications, power-options

I have a Note 4 running 6.0.1 that I recently reflashed back to stock in an attempt to fix issues I was having.

Now, whenever I enable Power Saving mode, it populates my notification list with a giant notification that takes up half the screen:

[image: Notification drawer]

I remember this happening when I first upgraded to Marshmallow, but at some point I did something that compacted the notification down to just the "turn off" button.

I don't care about having a little notification at the top, but all the "Your device performance is limited..." text is annoying.

Does anyone know what I might have down to fix this before? I'm pretty sure nothing I did was "hackish", and I didn't disable System UI notifications altogether since I still had the small one when Power Saving was enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out seconds after posting.

If you go into Power Saving settings and disable "Restrict all background data", the notification shrinks down. I must have had this disabled before.